# $X=int\{PQR\}\cup\{P,Q,R\}$,how many connected components are there in $X$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=int\{PQR\}\cup\{P,Q,R\}$ where $PQR$ is a triangle in a plane with usual topology, I need to know how many connected components are there in $X$, I think only one am I right?

Comment: seems you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  The only question is whether the vertex is a different component from the interior.  But for this to be the case there would have to be a separation of the vertex (say $P$) from the interior, disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ where the triangle's interior was a subset of $A$ and $P \in B$.

But $P$, being on the boundary of the interior of the triangle, is in the closure of the interior of the triangle, and therefore is in  the closure of $A$, which contains the closure of the interior of the triangle.  So $A, B$ was not a separation after all.